# Symfony2 Hateoas - My embedded resource appear twice in my serialized data

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, hateoas, jmsserializerbundle

I actually use Symfony2 with HateoasBundle from Will Durand, and I miss understand the embedded resource.

I have 2 entities, User and BlogArticle. BlogArticle contain a "user" property with a ManyToOne relation.

```
class BlogArticle implements ResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Kazooi\ApiBundle\Entity\User", fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;

    ...
}
```

Here is my serialized data in my file "Entity.BlogArticle.yml" :

```
Kazooi\ApiBundle\Entity\BlogArticle:
    exclusion_policy: none
    relations:
        -
            rel: self
            href:
                route: kazooi_api_blog_article_show
                parameters:
                    id: expr(object.getId())
                absolute: true
        -
            rel: user
            href:
                route: kazooi_api_user_show
                parameters:
                    id: expr(object.getUser())
                absolute: true
            embedded:
                content: expr(object.getUser())
            exclusion:
                exclude_if: expr(object.getUser() === null)
```

The result is :

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "coolfarmer",
    "username_canonical": "coolfarmer",
    "email": "test@hotmail.com",
    "email_canonical": "test@hotmail.com",
    "deleted": false,
    "_links": {
      "self": {
        "href": "http://api.kazooi.dev/1.0/users/1"
      }
    }
  },
  "title": "Ouverture de Kazooi",
  "message": "Lorém ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit",
  "date": "2016-02-24T00:00:00+0000",
  "tags": "one, two, three",
  "deleted": false,
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://api.kazooi.dev/1.0/blog/articles/1"
    },
    "user": {
      "href": "http://api.kazooi.dev/1.0/users/1"
    }
  },
  "_embedded": {
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "coolfarmer",
      "username_canonical": "coolfarmer",
      "email": "test@hotmail.com",
      "email_canonical": "test@hotmail.com",
      "deleted": false,
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://api.kazooi.dev/1.0/users/1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, the problem is that the user data appear twice, in the user property (because doctrine relation ManyToOne), and in _embedded because of my Hateoas relation definition.

It is normal? What i'm doing wrong or miss understanding.
I tought that the result should have been the same but the user property equal to "1", not the data.

PS : Entity in LAZY or EXTRA LAZY doesn't change the result.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [docs](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas#embedding-resources), you need to exclude the embedded property to avoid duplication.

So if you'd like to preserve the object under `_embedded`, you'd exclude the `user` property:

```
Kazooi\ApiBundle\Entity\BlogArticle:
    exclusion_policy: none
    relations:
        ...
        -
            rel: user
            href:
                route: kazooi_api_user_show
                parameters:
                    id: expr(object.getUser())
                absolute: true
            embedded:
                content: expr(object.getUser())
            exclusion:
                exclude_if: expr(object.getUser() === null)
    properties:
        user:
            exclude: true
```

If you'd like to keep the data as it is and get rid of the `_embedded` part, just remove the `embedded` key from the relation:

```
Kazooi\ApiBundle\Entity\BlogArticle:
    exclusion_policy: none
    relations:
        ...
        -
            rel: user
            href:
                route: kazooi_api_user_show
                parameters:
                    id: expr(object.getUser())
                absolute: true
            exclusion:
                exclude_if: expr(object.getUser() === null)
```

Comment: So _embedded is totally useless if you're using Doctrine. There is a way to set the hateoas resolver to OFF for some calls? Concept is cool, but if the resolver resolve 100% for each call, performance is affected.

Comment: You can use [groups](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies#creating-different-views-of-your-objects) to manage whether to include/exclude properties/relations based on the request, if that's what you mean. They also work with `Hateoas` as it's just an extension of the `JMSSerializer`.